# Can the steric nature of a carbon be quantified?

Tags: organic-chemistry

With respect to [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/small-doubt-regarding-bulkier-molecule-having-more-probabilty-of-reaction/35015?noredirect=1#comment53854_35015) question as suggested by a user (he asked me to ask this as a separate question), I wanted to know if there is any way in which steric hindarance of an organic carbon be quantified, as to a value that would indicate how bulky a compound is.

Comment: This has nothing to do with biochemistry. Please don't mistag on purpose.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by bulky? Are you referring to the steric bulk of different functional groups or some sort of measure of bulk of a molecule as a whole?

Comment: Bulky as in more bulky a compound more likely it is to react

Comment: @Rishika I'm afraid that doesn't make much sense. Generally steric bulk hinders a reaction by reducing the rate.

Comment: okay so steric bulk hindrance is a quantitative property?

Comment: Energy density or charge density quantify this, in some regard.

Comment: @khaverim can you please elaborate? in some regard as in?