# What constitutes something being designated as big, bulky in terms of SN2 vs E2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

When deciding between $\mathrm{S_N2}$ and $\mathrm{E2}$ for primary and secondary alkyl halides, is there a particular method or molecular size or any other threshold, which allows us to designate something as big and bulky?

Comment: I think you are referring to the fact that bulky nucleophiles hinder $\mathrm{S_N2}$, which is something you could have pointed out next time.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/can-bulky-nature-of-organic-compound-be-quantified http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35013/are-bulkier-molecules-more-likely-to-react